# How to select data from a Pandas series and get the data type not another object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe from which I select the first row to get a series. What is the best way to select data `nb` in order to get the integer `2`, not another series ?

My problem is that when I select `route.nb` I get a object instead of an integer.

This is how my series looks like:

```
# Dataframe to series
route = routes.iloc[0]

print(route)
level_1  level_2  level_3 
best                          -0.00228
nb                                   2
s1       cost     distance         0.0
                  city             NaN
                                ...   
s3       abcde    side             NaN

print(route.nb)
level_2  level_3
                    2
Name: 16, dtype: object


print(type(route.nb))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(len(route.nb))
1
```

As you can see I have one cell `nb` with value 2 and with `len(route.nb) == 1` but when I try to select the integer `2` it returns an object.

My question is how can I select the integer ? should I use `route.nb[0] even if it's not a list` ? Also, I notice that I can select other data from the series with `route.other_data` and get the integer (or string) not the object.

Multiindex of the series :

```
MultiIndex([(  'best',      '',           ''),
            ('length',      '',           ''),
            (    's1',  'cost',   'distance'),
            (    's1',  'cost',       'city'),
            ...
            (    's3',  'type',   'transfer')],
           names=['level_1', 'level_2', 'level_3'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the fact it’s the first element in the series:

```
route.iloc[0]
```

Or you can use the full index for that element:

```
route[('nb', '', '')]
```

When you do `route['nb']` it returns a series with the 2 remaining index levels. If you access the levels one by one:

```
route['nb']['']['']
```

Comment: Indeed, I noticed the indexing problem afterward. Thank you

Comment: Do you think it's not appropriate to select with `route.nb[0]` ? It works too

Comment: As long as you’ll remember what you meant by that when you come back to your code later @Florent, that’s all that matters :)